# Newest Application Loader strange message

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios5

I have strange error message that my application loader have after uploading application. 
It says:

**Transport type Signiant failed diagnostics; skipping**

And after that status for application on iTunes connect changes to normal Waiting for review.

Do anyone knows what this mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today everything normal no strange message in Application Loader.

Suppose was some kind of bug...